# Как задать нужное отображение "date" из MySQL посредством PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас отображение такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
  $mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo', 'rues');
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Подключение невозможно: ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $result_set = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM news');
  while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div id='ctitle'>". $row['title'] ."</div>";
    echo "<div id='news'>". $row['text'] ."</div>";
    echo $row['date'];
  }
  $result_set->close();
  $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ был получен, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: а как вы "отображаете" ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/unRF4p7.png

Comment: берете [`date`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) и форматируете как вам надо. Только дату mysql надо к [timestamp привести](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php). Еще вариант - [создаете дату](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.construct.php) и [форматируете ее](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php)

Comment: приведите код в самом вопросе, а не ссылкой на картинку в комментарии - это значительно увеличит шанс получить ответ :)

Comment: Простите, ваш ответ отличный, но мне не совсем понятно, где мне это редактировать.

Comment: @Artur кнопка "править" - прямо под самим вопросом

Comment: Я про изменение даты..

Comment: Еще вариант - сразу в [базе менять](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). На данный момент вам такое решение подойдет, но я бы не стал его использовать, т.к. в других местах может другой формат понадобится. Лучше приводить к нужному формату там, где это требуется, а не там, где вы это получаете.

Comment: @BOPOH да запостите ж вы нормальный ответ :)

Comment: мне только для одного места нужно, вывода новостей. Т.е. выводится новость, титл, текст и дата (и время) добавления в бд всей этой каши.
Больше, как думаю мне не понадобится это.

Comment: Не дубликат, извините.

Comment: @Artur, дубликат. От того, что вам надо пару параметров поменять, ваш вопрос уникальным не становится. Все параметры указаны в документации, можно хоть к кому виду приводить. В противном случае мы рискуем получить кучу однотипных вопросов, в которых вывод различается только положением компонент, т.е. надо то 12-30-2014, то 30-12-2014, то 2014-12-30 и т.д. получить.

Comment: Необходимый мне ответ я там не увидел. Мне ответили в моём вопросе более подробно и я узнал даже более-менее что-то новое. 
Считаю, что этот вопрос раскрыт более продуктивно. Всё же, прошу прощения за допущенное. Поиск по моим запросам не выдал необходимые мне результаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = date_create($row["date"]);
echo date_format($date, 'F d,Y - G:H');
```

Про формат подробней [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php).
Но округлять 12:45 до 13:00, если такая задача тоже стоит, надо уже руками.

Comment: Округления нет, это просто свободное время выбрано. Ваш ответ ценю, спасибо, буду тестить.